# Why don't people who are upset about economic inequality donate to the poor?

Tags: united-states, economy, social-welfare

The middle-class American often moans about economic inequality, but there's another aspect to the same issue as well: yes, the middle-class American makes far less than Donald Trump or Bill Gates, but the middle-class American also makes far more than some of the lower-class people struggling in poverty.

So if these middle-class average Americans really believe economic inequality is an issue, why do they always criticize the rich and do their [Occupy Wall Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupy_Wall_Street) movements, when they could just donate some of their own money to the poor? That would fix some of the inequality, would it not?

Comment: This question appears to be in good faith and seems easily answered.  Closers seem to be confusing bad faith with provincialism.

Comment: What is a "WS movement"? Also, at least one reference for "these middle-class average Americans really believe economic inequality is an issue, why do they always criticize the rich and do their occupy WS movements" would really help, especially for those outside US.

Comment: @Alexei he said "occupy WS movement" rather than "WS movement".  "Occupy Wall Street" was so widely reported, when it happened, that he most likely didn't think it needed to be spelled out.

Comment: What do you assume that middle-class average Americans do not donate some of their disposable income to the poor? Also, the aggregate disposable income of the middle class is small relative to the aggregate disposable income of the affluent. And there is no reason you can't push for both outcomes.

Comment: If you wish to balance a seesaw, do you lower the higher side, or the middle?

Answer (score 6):

From the viewpoint of their critics, the rich support shortsighted and defective policies that appear (to their critics) to have created and perpetuated Sisyphean cycles of needless impoverishment and misery.  Given such views, it would be strange if those critics *failed* to assign responsibility and to entreat corrective reforms.

By analogy:  suppose a poor old man is robbed, pleads for charity, and is immediately robbed again, then again pleads for charity, and is robbed yet *again*, and so on... providing that old man charity would be quite like providing charity for the robber.  The correct solution would be to prevent further robbery, and if possible to punish the robber as well.